# Which hypervisor is Google Compute Engine (GCE) using for its VM instances?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, cloud, google-cloud-platform

> Which hypervisor is Google Compute Engine (GCE) using for its VM instances?

Although it might be an implementation detail, I'm interested in knowing which hypervisor Google Compute Engine (GCE) is using for its VM instances.

Is Google using e.g. VMWare or LXC, or has Google developed its own hypervisor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia
[Google Compute Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Compute_Engine)
says in the section of
[Machine types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Compute_Engine#Machine_types):

> Google Compute Engine uses KVM as the hypervisor,[3] and supports guest images running Linux and Microsoft Windows which are used to launch virtual machines based on the 64 bit x86 architecture. VMs boot from a persistent disk that has a root filesystem. The number of virtual CPUs, amount of memory supported by the VM is dependent on the machine type selected.

So the answer is :
[Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine).